# How to set only year value in "XMLGregorianCalender" variable whose xmlSchemaType is "dateTime"

Tags: java, web-services, datetime, soap, wsdl

I am a Consumer of a SOAP Webservice. where we have one element named "Arrival" in stub given below. This got generated from providers WSDL.

```
@XmlElement(name = "Arrival", namespace = "https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/", required = true)

@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")

protected XMLGregorianCalendar arrival;
```

** As of now we are sending Full Datetime in this element but now they are expecting only "Year" value but when i tried doing it i am getting

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation xxxxxx.
```

Can anyone suggest me something on this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try these 2 steps.

1. Test your webservice using SOAP UI and make sure that passing Year value is working as expected.
2. Re-generate client classes using new WSDL file from provider.

If error persist and still have no idea about whats happening, Please post your request/response xml and new client class with arrival attribute.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually Provider is expecting this without changing their WSDL. So, I tried to do so with the existing stub which i showed earlier. But i got The mentioned error. So i want to be sure is this actually possible to set only the year value by using the stub which i posted in question? If it is possible then suggestions for this. Thanks in Advance.